# Java program for reading a text file and creating objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am currently writing a program to read in data from a text file and utilize the data in some way.  So far I can read the file no problem but the issue I am having is with what comes next.  As the data is read from the text file the appropriate objects must be created, from classes that I have already built,  and stored in 2 arrays based upon the data.  As I said before I have the code for the data to be read completed but I do not know how to use that data to create objects and to store those objects into arrays.

Here is the code that I have so far in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

        String fileLine;
        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("EmployeeData.txt"));

            System.out.println("Employee Data:");
            // Read one Line using BufferedReader
            while ((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(fileLine);
            }//end while
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("File IO exception" + io.getMessage());
        }finally {
            // Need another catch for closing 
            // the streams          
            try {               
                if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }                
            } catch (IOException io) {
                System.out.println("Issue closing the Files" + io.getMessage());
            }//end catch
        }//end finally
    }//end main method
```

Comment: Inside the `while` loop you can create the objects and add them to the arrays.

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you face in creating objects and adding them to the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about how data are represented in the text file and map them accordingly to the `Employee` class.

Take for instance if the `Employee` class is as below -

```
class Employee {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

}
```

and the lines in the file are like -

```
first1 last1
first2 last2
```

You can create an `arrayList` of `Employee` to hold the data -

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList();
```

When you read each line from the file, you can split the line by space, construct the object and add to the list -

```
String[] name = fileLine.split(" ");
Employee e = new Employee();
e.firstName = name[0];
e.lastName = name[1];

employees.add(e);
```

So basically, you have to consider the structure of the data in your source (text file) and figure out how you would parse them and construct your desired object.